Echo clicks to different windows on MacOS
Let's imagine I have a grid of windows, of the same application.
Window 1 | Window 2
-------------------
Window 3 | Window 4

Is there a way that I could click in a specific spot, let's say the left-hand corner of window 1, and have it echo across 2, 3, and 4?

This question was also posted at Ask Different, where the question was closed as a duplicate of this question. I believe posting the question twice is frowned upon.
